# Reserving slots in an SGE parallel environment

Tags: gridengine

I'm trying to set up a Parallel Environment in SGE, with allocation rule `$pe_slots`, but I'm having trouble with the scheduler.

Single-core jobs hog the slots; there are never enough slots open at one moment for multi-core jobs get scheduled.

Can SGE notice when multi-core jobs have been waiting a long time, and reserve slots for them, rather than letting single-slot jobs continuously butt in line?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do this automatically but if you have a non-zero max_reservation in your sched_conf you can add -R y to your qsub options to enable reserving resources for a job when it is high priority.  On our clusters we have a jsv that examines the job requests and adds -R y as needed.